# Issue whit getExternalFilesDir, can't find my dir in DDMS

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I wrote the following code:

```
String check=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (check.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        Log.d("exito","exito");
    }
    File file= new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/Terrible","otracosa");
    file.mkdir();
    Log.d("cosaboleano",Boolean.toString(file.exists()));
    if (file.exists()) {
        Log.d("cosa2", "tará!!!");
    }
```

I added this permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Got this output from Logs:

```
08-09 17:55:03.575 29236-29236/com.example.ruelas.downloadpractice D/exito: exito
08-09 17:55:03.578 29236-29236/com.example.ruelas.downloadpractice D/cosaboleano: true
08-09 17:55:03.578 29236-29236/com.example.ruelas.downloadpractice D/cosa2: tará!!!
```

And looked for my files in mnt/sdcard and nothing is there:
[image: My Android Picture]

Where do I have to look for y allegedly created files? Do I have to create an aditional virtual SD card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> emulated ->0  -> yo will find your all sdcard data there